# What is the difference between %s and %c format specifier?

Tags: c, format-specifiers

In my knowledge the `%c` expects the int value (as `char` is treated as integer in **C**), and `%s` expects the `char *` as argument, but  my doubt is, **does the %s need a pointer to a block of  characters? Can it points to a single character in double quotes?**

For example:

```
char * s = "string"; 
printf("%s",s);// output: string
```

How is the compiler able to figure out the block of memory where the string is present and terminated by `'\0'`?.

Comment: Yes, it can point to a length-1 string.

Comment: A single character in *double* quotes is still a C string, i.e., it is NUL terminated, unlike a single character inside single quotes.

Answer (score 4):

A single character in double quote still is a C-String, actually containing two characters: The single character plus the terminating null character:

```
char const* str = "a"; // actually points to an array { 'a', '\0' }
```

So you still use it with `%s`. Actually, you *can* use it with `%c`, too, if you dereference the string:

```
printf("%c\n", *str);
//             ^
```

You could do that with any C-String (with exception of the empty one ""), but only the first character would then be printed...

*Addition in response to your comment:*

Function calls (at least with cdecl and stdcall calling conventions) are done by placing the function arguments onto the stack (on most modern systems, types smaller than int are promoted to int on the stack). `printf` then simply parses the format string, if it discovers %s, it will interprete the next `sizeof(void*)` bytes on the stack as a pointer to a null terminated string (thus pass `str` directly), if it discovers %c, it reads a character directly from the stack -- so you need to place one there and not a pointer, thus you need to dereference.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `str[0]` instead of `*str`.

Comment: @Aconcagua why %c needs to deference the str ,but %s not ?

Comment: @Matec009 Added some additional information to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

> how compiler is able to figure out the block of memory where the
>   string present and terminated by '\0' ?.

Because a string literal (x amount of characters between double quotes) gets the NUL terminator `\0` added to it by the compiler.

```
char * s = "string"; 
char foo = s[6]; // \0
```

So `printf` just prints the characters of the string until it finds a `\0`.

> is the %s needs pointer to a block of character . can it points to a
>   single character in double quote ?

Yes you can, a single character in double quotes is still a string literal with a `\0` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The string is made up of character, just as the char array is made up if characters.

Compilers should be smart, and gcc  must have a function that can identify which is which, and peform the appropriate operations (such as adding a null terminator)

And to answer your question, yes it will still print to the console, just as

```
char * s = "string"; 
printf("%s",s);// output: string
```

Will print to the console.